# I am trying to remember the name and/or author of a fantasy trilogy written I think in the 1980s or 90s set on another planet

Tags: story-identification

The world is matriarchal.  I remember it starting with a girl running away from home because she was scared of being "chosen" to become a priestess (??).  Technology was actively discouraged and time/energy went towards improving healing powers.  I think the "priestesses" cured the ill in the villages.  There was a research space station that was watching them because their planet was not being consumed by evil like others in the universe.  I can't remember much more except that at one point she denied doing something 3 times which resulted in her being somehow special.  If anyone has a clue - it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like maybe Ursula K. Le Guin, but I can't think of the title.